# cpanel git version control. Is there a way to run the laravel migration automatically after the code is updated?

Tags: php, git, terminal, cpanel, laravel-artisan

I can update my code on cPanel using git version control. At the moment I then have to go to the terminal and run the artisan migrate command. Can this be added together to make one step?
This is my workflow:

This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions
name: CI
Controls when the workflow will run
on:

Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
push:
branches: [ main ]
Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
workflow_dispatch:
A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:

This workflow contains a single job called "build"
job_one:
name: Deploy
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- name: executing remote ssh commands using ssh keys
uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
with:
host: hostgoeshere
username: uknet
key: ${{ secrets.CPANEL }}
#password: passwordgoeshere
port: 7822
script: |
cd /home/uknet/public_html/master
pwd
git add .
git stash
git pull origin main
git status

Is it possible to add a terminal line at the bottom with `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: If you're asking "is it possible, somehow, to write a system that achieves what I want" then the answer is of course yes. You just sit down and write it. If you mean "does cpanel itself have that feature" then that's a question about cpanel, not about Git or terminal emulators or the php language. Pick something more specific and ask that.